# How to ask Automapper to grab related record by inner join on Id field which is not a foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I’ve been using Automapper for a while now, and so far it all works great. But recently I came across some “limitation” (or lack of my knowledge).
Let me give you a simplified example with two classes:

```
public class Consumable 
{
    public int ConsumableId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int SaleDepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class SaleDepartment 
{
    public int SaleDepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

These two entities store the Id of SaleDepartment, but there is not foreign key linking SaleDepartment to Consumable (and I don’t want it as a key), however SaleDepartment has PrimaryKey on SaleDepartmentId

Now my DTO looks very similar

```
public class ConsumableDTO 
{
    public int ConsumableId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int SaleDepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Consumable, ConsumableDTO>().ReverseMap();
```

So anytime I bring a Collection of ConsumableDTO’s I also want to bring the related SaleDepartment’s descriptions,
If there was a navigation property I would do something like this

```
Mapper.Map<ObservableCollection<Consumable>>
(context.Consumable.Project().To<ConsumableDTO>());
```

But because such a key does not exist, how would I tell the automapper to do inner join based on these Ids I have?
I have spent two days and I found a way of doing it, but I am not convinced that this the right way, and I am wondering whether I am missing a trick here and there is an easier or better way of achieving this with the automapper.

This is how I achieved getting the related record

```
var foo = new ObservableCollection<Consumable>(
          (from c in context.Consumable.Project().To<ConsumableDTO>()
           join sd in context.SaleDepartment on c.SaleDepartmentId equals sd.SaleDepartmentId
           select new
           {
               consumable = c,
               SaleDepartmentDescription = sd.Description
           }).ToList()
           .Select(p => Mapper.Map<ConsumableDTO, Consumable>(p.consumable, new Consumable() 
           {
               SaleDepartmentDescription = p.SaleDepartmentDescription
           })));
```

So, this will grab or consumable and then inner join saledeparments and select description form that inner join, but it seems like quite few steps, is there an easier way of telling the automapper, grab that related record based on this matching Id?

Thank you for your attention and time.

Comment: Just a question. Right now when you are querying Consumable (not DTO) you bring the SaleDepartment? You could create an SaleDepartment property inside Consumable and when you fetch a consumable, just fill the SaleDepartment.

Comment: @jpgrassi Thank you for your suggestion, thats right I have tried it and it does it, however I only need SaleDepartmentDescription. So if I create SaleDepartmentDTO and have one property in it, it will work just fine, but then I get SaleDepartment with 20 properties (19 empty), but I only need one. Also, when there are two navigations to the same table, entity framework throws an exception, the code in my question would work I can easily add another join and then select another field. But is there anything inside the Automapper which would do these joins for me? Hopefully it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming your DTO is meant to contain `public string SaleDepartmentDescription { get; set; }` as your question refers to it but it isn't actually there.

If you are NOT using EF migrations (a fair assumption since otherwise you'd just add the foreign key!), then you can do this by adding keys in your Entities - the keys don't actually need to present in the database for EF to join on them, this just tells EF to pretend that they are.  (If you are using EF migrations then this approach will not work, as it will want to add the keys to the DB.)

```
public class Consumable 
{
    public int ConsumableId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int SaleDepartmentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SaleDepartmentId")]
    public virtual SaleDepartment SaleDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming your DTO *does* contain the string property `SaleDepartmentDescription` then AutoMapper will handle this automatically, though you should use ProjectTo to make more efficient database queries:

```
var mappedDTOs = context.Consumable.ProjectTo<ConsumableDTO>().ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn’t know I can have foreign key if it does not exist in the database. Your solution works I just had to add to Mapper this, 
Mapper.CreateMap<ConsumableDTO, Consumable>().ReverseMap().ForMember(p => p.SaleDepartmentDescription, config => config.MapFrom(sd => sd.SaleDepartment.Description)); it does exactly what I need, it bring this one field only, and stores it in notmapped property instead of having the entire saledepartment with empty properties.